# Keycloak fastapi user registry

Tags: fastapi

So I was testing a way to add more users to keycloak and I found this way:

```
keycloak_connection = KeycloakOpenIDConnection(
                        server_url="http://localhost:8080/*",
                        username='test',
                        password='1234',
                        realm_name="test_admin",
                        client_id="test_admin_user",
                        client_secret_key="1111111111111",
                        verify=True)

keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(connection=keycloak_connection)

# Add user
new_user = keycloak_admin.create_user({"email": "test_email",
                                       "username": "alias",
                                       "enabled": True,
                                       "firstName": "top",
                                       "lastName": "top1"})
```

But then when I try this with keycloak I see this error:

```
keycloak.exceptions.KeycloakPostError: 403: b'{"error":"unknown_error","error_description":"For more on this error consult the server log at the debug level."}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'admin-cli' client and user has `realm-management` manage-users role.

[image]

##### launching Keycloak

In your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78101985/keycloack-and-postgres-docker-compose/78103098#78103098)

##### Demo code

Save as `create-user.py`

```py
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenIDConnection, KeycloakAdmin

keycloak_connection = KeycloakOpenIDConnection(
                        server_url="http://localhost:8180",
                        username='test',
                        password='1234',
                        realm_name="test_admin",
                        user_realm_name="test_admin",
                        client_id="admin-cli",
                        verify=True
)
keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(connection=keycloak_connection)

# Add user
users = keycloak_admin.get_users()

isAlias = False
for user in users:
  print("user:", user['username'])
  if (user['username'] == "alias"):
    isAlias = True

if (not isAlias):
    new_user = keycloak_admin.create_user({
        "email": "test_email@test.com",
        "username": "alias",
        "enabled": True,
        "emailVerified": True,
        "firstName": "top",
        "lastName": "top1"
        })
    print("alias registered")
```

##### Result

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help, can you please send me the documentation where this is?

Comment: @rainbow12, I referenced two documentation. One is [Python Keycloak](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/) other is my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77964117/problem-with-connecting-to-keycloak-server-using-python-keycloak-package/77965991#77965991), Can you accept and up-vote for my answer?

Comment: @rainbow12, I have a little Keycloak concept & experience, If you want to know for more about Keycloak. Asked in Overflow flow. I can help you.

Comment: That would be great! where can we talk?

Comment: You leave a message in here, Or you can make char room, I have no idea how to create a room.

Comment: I need to set up a session key from the js to store the refresh token. Do you have any topics that can point me to and help?

Comment: I handled access token before in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77964117/problem-with-connecting-to-keycloak-server-using-python-keycloak-package/77965991#77965991) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/), you can find refresh token. If not success make a new question, I can help you.

Comment: thank you, I just did this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78156424/set-session-cookie-instead-of-sessionstorage

Comment: OK, I will try it when I return home.

Comment: @rainbow12,  I wonder for your tag. Why you add a tag `fastapi`, I think your question just `python`, `keycloak` and `python-keycloak`, I cant find ho to related with `fastapi`?

Comment: Sorry but are you referring to the question i posted?

Comment: OK, I got it this question no API decorator but your new question has `@app.post`, So that makes sense.