# Get cookie sent to js

Tags: fastapi

So I'm passing now a cookie from keycloack endpoint login to the FE. This is my code:

```
@app.post("/user/login", response_model=dict)
async def login(form_user:str,form_pass:str, response: Response):

    token_response= keycloak_openid.token(grant_type="password", username=form_user, password=form_pass)

    access_token=token_response["access_token"]
    refresh_token= token_response["refresh_token"]
    response.set_cookie(key="session_id", value=access_token, httponly=True, path="/")
    return {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
    }
```

But then, I can see the cookie is being passed by the js but I cannot access it in the BE again.
I'm trying to access it like this:

```
@app.get("/something"):
def get_cookie(req:Request):
     access_cookie= request.cookies.get("session_id")
```

when I try to see the content of access_cookie I got it has None.

Comment: I try find to get `refresh token` but I can't find it. Due to KeycloakOpenIDConnection() have no scope parameter, I can't payload with "offline_access" scope. So my quick conclusion, no way to get refresh token by `KeycloakOpenIDConnection`, From manual can do but I failed. Sorry.

Comment: but the thing is, I already can get the refresh token, the only thing that I'm not seeing is the cookie set on the code that I posted. Should I set it differently?

Comment: I will try again when I return home.

Comment: I edit my question to be more specific now @BenchVue

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74407063/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060795/17865804)

Comment: but what I don't get is how can I retrieve the cookie from the token endpoint, at least in this case @Chris

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662576/17865804) might help as well.