Keycloak reponse 403 Forbidden when trying to register new user
I want to register a new user in keycloak.
I tried to setup all roles, but still i get 403
Forbidden error.
It doesn't matter whether I test it directly with Postman or through the backend app.
docker-compose.yml
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3
    container_name: testKeycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    command:
      - start-dev
      - --import-realm
      - --http-port=9090
      - --log-level=DEBUG
      - --debug
    volumes:
      - ./test-realm.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/test-realm.json
    networks:
      - test

{
  "realm": "test-realm",
  "enabled": true,
  "accessTokenLifespan": 2592000,
  "roles": {
    "realm": [
      {
        "name": "USER",
        "description": "User role"
      },
      {
        "name": "ADMIN",
        "description": "Admin role"
      },
      {
        "name": "USER-MANAGEMENT",
        "description": "Role for managing user registration",
        "composite": true,
        "composites": {
          "client": {
            "realm-management": ["view-users", "manage-users"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "user1",
      "enabled": true,
      "emailVerified": true,
      "firstName": "User",
      "lastName": "One",
      "email": "user1@example.com",
      "credentials": [
        {
          "type": "password",
          "value": "password",
          "temporary": false
        }
      ],
      "realmRoles": [
        "USER"
      ]
    },
    {
      "username": "admin1",
      "enabled": true,
      "emailVerified": true,
      "firstName": "Admin",
      "lastName": "One",
      "email": "admin1@example.com",
      "credentials": [
        {
          "type": "password",
          "value": "password",
          "temporary": false
        }
      ],
      "realmRoles": [
        "USER",
        "ADMIN"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "clients": [
    {
      "clientId": "test-backend",
      "enabled": true,
      "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
      "secret": "your-backend-secret",
      "redirectUris": [
        "http://localhost:3030/*"
      ],
      "webOrigins": [
        "+"
      ],
      "publicClient": false,
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "fullScopeAllowed": false,
      "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,
      "authorizationServicesEnabled": true,
      "standardFlowEnabled": true,
      "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true
    }
  ]
}

After Keycloak startup, I'm logging into the admin console and adding
Clients -> test-backend -> assign USER-MANAGEMENT
I tried to setup all roles, but still i get 403
Forbidden error.
It doesn't matter whether I test it directly with Postman or through the backend app.
keycloak log:
24-11-13 13:45:50,046 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) Error response 403: org.keycloak.services.ForbiddenException
2024-11-13T13:45:50.048050500Z  at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.permissions.UserPermissions.requireManage(UserPermissions.java:253)
2024-11-13T13:45:50.048057629Z  at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UsersResource.createUser(UsersResource.java:118)
2024-11-13T13:45:50.048060001Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-11-13T13:45:50.048062211Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2024-11-13T13:45:50.048065171Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-11-13T13:45:50.048068098Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
2024-11-13T13:45:50.048071812Z  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
decoded generated token:
"iat": 1731506955,
  "jti": "ef928236-e7b2-4bdb-8748-c4309dabbf7d",
  "iss": "http://localhost:9090/realms/test-realm",
  "sub": "df6f8347-7824-49b7-877f-f22d1ecb1f21",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "test-backend",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "http://localhost:3030"
  ],
  "resource_access": {
    "test-backend": {
      "roles": [
        "uma_protection"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "email profile",
  "clientId": "test-backend",
  "clientHost": "172.21.0.1",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "service-account-test-backend",
  "clientAddress": "172.21.0.1"
}


If you can't get it to work on the backend, how can you be sure your credentials are correct?

Because im generating token

the "test-backend" client needs to assign manage-users role. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78110110/keycloak-fastapi-user-registry/78111662#78111662

Finally, I found a solution.
To my configuration.json, I have added this under "users":
{
  "username": "service-account-test-backend",
  "enabled": true,
  "serviceAccountClientId": "test-backend",
  "clientRoles": {
    "realm-management": [
      "view-users",
      "manage-users",
      "query-users"
    ]
  }
}

Under "test-backend" client:
"protocolMappers": [
  {
    "name": "client roles",
    "protocol": "openid-connect",
    "protocolMapper": "oidc-usermodel-client-role-mapper",
    "consentRequired": false,
    "config": {
      "multivalued": "true",
      "userinfo.token.claim": "true",
      "id.token.claim": "true",
      "access.token.claim": "true",
      "claim.name": "resource_access.${client_id}.roles",
      "jsonType.label": "String"
    }
  }
]

And at the end in the main file:
"clientScopes": [
  {
    "name": "test-backend-scope",
    "protocol": "openid-connect",
    "attributes": {},
    "protocolMappers": [],
    "clientScopeMappings": {
      "realm-management": [
        {
          "client": "test-backend",
          "roles": [
            "view-users",
            "manage-users",
            "query-users"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

